# Time series from dataframe loses values

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series

I have 2 dataframes, `df1` and `df2` of the same size, `df1`with a `date`column and  `df2` with a `float` column. When I do the following:

```
series = pandas.Series(df2['float'], df1['date'])
```

The values on the time series are all `NaN`. I've checked both dataframes have data before doing it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying here? Are you wanting the float or the date values as the index and the other as data?

Comment: Date as index, therefore second argument.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or not but the following works: `series = pandas.Series(df2['float'].values, df1['date'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me:

```
In [29]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime.now()]})
print(df)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'float':[2.1145]})
df1
                        date
0 2015-02-23 11:23:03.550538
Out[29]:
    float
0  2.1145
In [30]:

pd.Series(df1['float'], df['date'])
Out[30]:
date
2015-02-23 11:23:03.550538   NaN
Name: float, dtype: float64
```

It works if you call the attribute `.values`:

```
In [31]:

pd.Series(df1['float'].values, df['date'])
Out[31]:
date
2015-02-23 11:23:03.550538    2.1145
dtype: float64
```

This looks like a generic bug:

```
In [34]:

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'int':[323]})
df3
Out[34]:
   int
0  323
```

The following combinations all fail:

```
In [39]:

pd.Series(df2['float'], df3['int'])
Out[39]:
int
323   NaN
Name: float, dtype: float64
In [40]:

pd.Series(df['date'], df2['float'])
Out[40]:
float
1.21554   NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [41]:

pd.Series(df3['int'], df2['float'])
Out[41]:
float
1.21554   NaN
Name: int, dtype: float64
```

Comment: reported here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9456. Its actually a pretty trivial fix. pull-requests welcome!

Comment: @Jeff thanks Jeff, was trying to step through this and see what was going on, seems to happen when it goes through the super call via: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L159 if I ever get this sucker to compile properly on Win 7 64-bit (or buy a mac) and some time I'll see if I can contribute more